Remote desktop audio needs fixing after sleep
Weird thing. I remote into a local Windows 10 computer every day. I put both computers to sleep at night and wake it in the morning. Every morning, the audio doesn't work until I right-click on the audio icon in the taskbar -> Troubleshoot sound problems -> then let it scan, let it do the beep, let it scan again, then voila, it works again (but says it couldn't find the issue).
I've tried multiple things:

NVidia likes to install HD Audio but I uninstalled that and keep it
from re-installing.
Ran services.msc -> Remote Desktop Services
UserMode Port Redirector -> set to automatic.
Stopped and restarted Remote Desktop services.

Anyone have an idea on what could be happening here or a way to debug it?
